# Strange output from bash one liner

Tags: linux, bash, glob, brace-expansion

While in the course of learning bash, I often tweak an existing thing and see it's output.

```
~$ for i in {1..19}; do echo "Everything in UNIX is a file."; sleep 1; done
```

I had this, and out of curiosity I tweaked the above one into the following:-

```
~$ for i in {1..19 * 2}; do echo "Everything in UNIX is a file."; echo "The value of i is ${i}";  sleep 1; done
```

Now to my surprise I started getting the following output :-

```
Everything in UNIX is a file.
The value of i is OneDrive
Everything in UNIX is a file.
The value of i is opera autoupdate
Everything in UNIX is a file.
The value of i is Personal_Workspace
Everything in UNIX is a file.
The value of i is Pictures
Everything in UNIX is a file.
The value of i is PrintHood
Everything in UNIX is a file.
The value of i is Recent
Everything in UNIX is a file.
The value of i is Roaming
Everything in UNIX is a file.
The value of i is Saved Games
Everything in UNIX is a file.
The value of i is Searches
```

Some of the values of i are the names of files and directories in my home directory, I am in home directory, while executing this script.

What I was expecting that the i values would range from 1 to 19*2 = 38, so i would take values from 1,2,3...30...38.
But obviously it did n't Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes in `bash`, range expansion happens before everything else. You were expecting arithmetic expansion to happen *which* did not happen as expected because of the order of expansion `bash` shell. Your code ended up interpreting `{1..19`, `*` and `2}` as literal strings.

Since `*` has a special meaning in shell which is a glob expansion listing all files/directories in current folder. Also you could see one entry stating the other two strings interpreted literally.

From the [man bash(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) page under section `Expansion`

> The order of expansions is: brace expansion, tilde expansion, parameter, variable and arithmetic expansion and command substitution (done in a left-to-right fashion), word splitting, and pathname expansion.

You are much better off using a `for` loop with a `((..))` construct if you are targeting scripts for bourne again shell

```
for ((i=1; i<=38; i++)); do
```

Comment: This is the good answer now that you added the part about literal strings :) +1

Answer (score 2):

The `*` symbol in unix shell translates to a wildcard, so basically what `{1..19 * 2}` means is 1 through 19, all files in current dir (that's the *), and than 2. these will be the values of i in your loop

Comment: This (well not exactly, it won't loop from 1 to 19 but treat "{1..19" as a string). Try with `+` instead of `*` to see the output more clearly. Which will output "{1..19", then "+" and finally "2}".

Comment: Actually the values are first `{1..19` then second all the files then third `2}`